# What is wrong with this reasoning in proving that $||\textbf{x}||^3$ is convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am trying to prove that $||\textbf{x}||^3$ is convex by showing that $$||\lambda \textbf{x}_1+(1-\lambda)\textbf{x}_2||^3\leq \lambda||\textbf{x}_1||^3+(1-\lambda)||\textbf{x}_2||^3$$ where $0\leq \lambda\leq1$. On the left hand side I use $$||\lambda \textbf{x}_1+(1-\lambda)\textbf{x}_2||\cdot||\lambda \textbf{x}_1+(1-\lambda)\textbf{x}_2||\cdot||\lambda \textbf{x}_1+(1-\lambda)\textbf{x}_2||\leq (\lambda ||\textbf{x}_1||+(1-\lambda)||\textbf{x}_2||)^3$$ After this if I could prove that $$\lambda||\textbf{x}_1||^3+(1-\lambda)||\textbf{x}_2||^3-(\lambda ||\textbf{x}_1||+(1-\lambda)||\textbf{x}_2||)^3\geq 0$$ then it is obvious that $||\textbf{x}||$ is convex but unfortunately I am unable to show this (the result I get is given below) $$(1-\lambda)\left[\lambda ||\textbf{x}_1||^3(1-\lambda)+||\textbf{x}_2||^3(1-(1-\lambda)^2)-3\lambda^2||\textbf{x}_1||^2||\textbf{x}_2||-3\lambda ||\textbf{x}_1||(1-\lambda)||\textbf{x}_2||^2\right]$$ (which is not obvious to be positive). Is there any other way through which I could show that $||\textbf{x}||^3$ is convex? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "After this if I ..." I think there is some \leq or something like that missing..

Comment: @lush corrected. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Tip: Use `\|` for double vertical bars instead of `||`: $\|\mathbf x\|$ vs. $||\mathbf x||$.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if $f$ is convex and $g$ is non-decreasing and convex then the composition $g\circ f$ is convex:
$$
g\left(f\left(\lambda \textbf{x}_1+(1-\lambda)\textbf{x}_2\right)\right) 
\le g\left(\lambda f(\textbf{x}_1) + (1 - \lambda) f(\textbf{x}_2)\right) 
\le \lambda g(f(\textbf{x}_1)) + (1 - \lambda)g(f(\textbf{x}_2)).$$
Take $f(x)=\|\textbf{x}\|$ and $g(x)=x^3$ (which is convex in $[0,+\infty)$).

Answer (score 1):

Which theorems can you use? For onedimensional twice differentiable functions
you can use

> $$
> f\text{ is convex }\Leftrightarrow f''\geq 0.
> $$

This implies that $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$, $f(x)=x^3$ is convex. You can conclude 
\begin{align*}
\lambda||\textbf{x}_1||^3+(1-\lambda)||\textbf{x}_2||^3
&=\lambda f(\|\textbf{x}_1\|)+(1-\lambda)f(\|\textbf{x}_2\|)\\
&\geq f(\lambda\|\textbf{x}_1\|+(1-\lambda)\|\textbf{x}_2\|)\\
&=(\lambda ||\textbf{x}_1||+(1-\lambda)||\textbf{x}_2||)^3
\end{align*}

Comment: Mundron.Correct me Frank tried to prove the inequality , convexity, and could not. You, in a way move bachwards, means, with the help of the f'' theorem, hence convex, you prove the inequality.In other words for this special f you show that f'' implies convexity.Your take?